# Add a View Older Posts button or link ASP.NET Repeater Control

Tags: asp.net, repeater

How to set ASP.NET Repeater control to only display 10 items & add a link or a button so if you press it it displays 10 more items again i don't mean erase the other 10 i want to keep the & add another 10 below them.

P.S i know how to set it to read only 10 but how to make it read another 10 & display it below?

Comment: You can simple add a second repeater, with the next 10 items, that is hidden, with the button click you make it visible and show the next 10 lines. All that inside an update panel. You do not bind it when is hidden.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45163/Extend-Repeater-to-support-DataPager

Comment: @Aristos this would work if i wan to display only 20, i want with every button click to add another 10 & another & another. & thx for ur time

Comment: @Tariqulazam Paging is not my problem but thanks for your time any way.

Comment: @BeyondProgramming Yes, this is the idea, you simple add dynamic one repeater on each button click.

Comment: @Aristos Aha i'll try that & post the result, again thx for your time :D

Comment: @BeyondProgramming I after some test I see that is difficult to make dynamic the repeater. The best is to create a custom control that contains the view you like to show, and dynamic create that one the times you like + the extra ones on each click.

Comment: @Aristos Thx for your answer, I implemented it added a repeater dynamically each time button clicked with new id for each one & it worked just Fine, i'll tidy my code & put it for every one to learn from & help any one who faces the same problem :D.

Comment: @BeyondProgramming just wondering did you ever get around to putting your code up anywhere? i am stuck with exactly the same issue at the minute :(

Comment: @AndyKirkpatrick man that was like a year ago, However you can achieve that behavior using AJAJ (Asynchronous JavaScript and JSON), You can asynchronously request the data you need on a certain client triggered event then when the data is received you can use some library like knockout to update your UI with the newely retrieved data, Hope this helps :).